# Getting Error while sending - No SRV record found for: _jabber._tcp.Username

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am using openfire to send chat massage from android client i am getting massages from spark client but not able to send massage to spark client I am getting following error :

```
 at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) 
 at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) 
 at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.DNSUtil.srvLookup(DNSUtil.java:192) 
 at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.DNSUtil.resolveXMPPDomain(DNSUtil.java:124) 
 org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalOutgoingServerSession.authenticateDomain
 (LocalOutgoin      gServerSession.java:167) 
 org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.OutgoingSessionPromise$
 PacketsProcessor.sendPacket(OutgoingSessionPromise.java:261) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.OutgoingSessionPromise$
PacketsProcessor.run(OutgoingSessionPromise.java:238) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
2014.11.20 12:35:36 org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.DNSUtil - 
No SRV record found for: _jabber._tcp.test 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3];
remaining     name '_jabber._tcp.test' 
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.checkResponseCode(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.isMatchResponse(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.doUdpQuery(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsClient.query(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.dns.Resolver.query(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContext.c_getAttributes(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_getAttributes(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) 
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) 
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getAttributes(Unknown Source) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.DNSUtil.srvLookup(DNSUtil.java:192) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.DNSUtil.resolveXMPPDomain(DNSUtil.java:126) 
org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalOutgoingServerSession.
createOutgoingSession(LocalOutgoingServerSession.java:270) 
atorg.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalOutgoingServerSession.
authenticateDomain(LocalOutgoingServerSession.java:167) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.OutgoingSessionPromise$PacketsProcessor.
sendPacket(OutgoingSessionPromise.java:261) 
atorg.jivesoftware.openfire.server.OutgoingSessionPromise$
PacketsProcessor.run(OutgoingSessionPromise.java:238) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
 2014.11.20 12:35:36 org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.
LocalOutgoingServerSession -  LocalOutgoingServerSession: OS - Trying to connect to
test:5269(DNS lookup: test:5269) 
2014.11.20 12:35:38 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.
ClientConnectionHandler -  [/######:1242] Filtered Write: 
org.apache.mina.filter.support.SSLHandler@1d53274 
org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ClientConnectionHandler - 
org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ClientConnectionHandler - 
 Wrap  res:Status = OK  HandshakeStatus = NOT_HANDSHAKING 
bytesConsumed = 190 bytesProduced = 211 
org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Launching thread for  
org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.OutgoingSessionPromise -
OutgoingSessionPromise: Error    sending packet to *****server: 
<message id="zg34L-9" to="test" type="chat" from="demo@localhost/Smack"> 
<body>hi</body> 
</message> 
java.lang.Exception: Failed to create connection to remote server 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.OutgoingSessionPromise$PacketsProcessor.
sendPacket(Outgoing   SessionPromise.java:274) 
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.server.OutgoingSessionPromise$
PacketsProcessor.run(OutgoingSession   Promise.java:238) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
org.apache.mina.filter.executor.ExecutorFilter - Exiting since queue is empty for 



public class XMPPChatDemoActivity extends Activity {

public static final String HOST = "#########";
public static final int PORT = 5222;

public static final String USERNAME = "demo@servername";
public static final String PASSWORD = "demo";
public static final String SERVICE = "servername";
private XMPPConnection connection;
private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private EditText recipient;
private EditText textMessage;
private ListView listview;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    recipient = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.toET);
    textMessage = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.chatET);
    listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
    setListAdapter();

    // Set a listener to send a chat text message
    Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String to = recipient.getText().toString();
            String text = textMessage.getText().toString();

            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.sendPacket(msg);
                messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
                messages.add(text);
                setListAdapter();
                Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "--------------------------------------");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "User: " + entry.getUser());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Name: " + entry.getName());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Type: " + entry.getType());
                    Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                            .getUser());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                            + entryPresence.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                            + entryPresence.getType());
                    Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                    if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                            + entryPresence);
                    // Toast.makeText(XMPPChatDemoActivity.this,
                    // "gettting user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            } else{
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "no massage send");
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                        + connection.getUser());
            }
        }
    });

    connect();
}
/**
 * Called by Settings dialog when a connection is establised with the XMPP
 * server
 * 
 * @param connection
 */
public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    if (connection != null) {
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Message message = (Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message
                            .getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Text Recieved "
                            + message.getBody() + " from " + fromName);
                    messages.add(fromName + ":");
                    messages.add(message.getBody());
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            setListAdapter();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }
}

private void setListAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.listitem, messages);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void connect() {

    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,
            "Connecting...", "Please wait...", false);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Create a connection
            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Connected to " + connection.getHost());

                // Toast.makeText(XMPPChatDemoActivity.this,
                // "Connected to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "
                        + connection.getHost());
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
                // Toast.makeText(XMPPChatDemoActivity.this,
                // "Failed to connect ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try {
                // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                        "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                // Set the status to available
                Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                connection.sendPacket(presence);
                setConnection(connection);

                Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "--------------------------------------");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "User: " + entry.getUser());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Name: " + entry.getName());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Type: " + entry.getType());
                    Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry
                            .getUser());

                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "
                            + entryPresence.getStatus());
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "
                            + entryPresence.getType());
                    Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                    if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "
                            + entryPresence);
                    // Toast.makeText(XMPPChatDemoActivity.this,
                    // "gettting user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "
                        + USERNAME);
                Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                setConnection(null);
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    t.start();
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

i am using embedded openfire pls suggest me any idea for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the host part of the user you're sending the message to. You want to send it to `test@localhost`, by sending it to just `test`, the server starts looking for another server with hostname `test` (which fails).